# Data scraping from a website that does a server-side data processing via DataTables and Ajax

Tags: javascript, websocket, screen-scraping

I am trying to automate a data scraping procedure from a website that does a server-side data fetching and loads data on demand (on scrolling down through that table). From doing some googling and looking into their website code through DevTools, I understand that [this functionality](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) is being used to push data into the table using JS and ajax. The api link to pull the data from the server most likely sits in a php script and cannot be obtained.

I was wondering if it's possible to automate this extraction procedure somehow (Python/R) so that I don't have to manually scroll for hours and copy-paste the data into an Excel file?

Comment: Use 'Network' tab of devtools to grab API endpoint. Then simply use that url (modified within the loop) to fetch the entire table.Very easy.

Comment: This particular page you're showing isn't using server-side processing at all. It *fakes* it. But if someone were using this API, it would be entirely possible to hit the server-side end-point and fetch the data. Without an actual example of what you're struggling with I can't provide further help, but yes it's entirely possible.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov That's the thing, I can't find an API endpoint. I agree, it's easy once you have it.

Comment: Share URL of the page you're trying to scrap.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov https://www.deribit.com/main#/options?tab=all. The table at the bottom "Recent Trades CALLS"

Comment: That table (`$('#last_trades_call').closest('table')`) has `bServerSide: false` and 200 records, that's why it doesn't do any XHR's while you scroll.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov are you saying that there should not be a php script fetching the data? In that case I don't fully understand how is the data being loaded.

Comment: @Sherif yes, I understand that in that particular example it's fake data. Please see the website/table I'm trying to scrape data from in my comment above

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant details of what you're trying to do and what you've tried so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.deribit.com/ is using a web socket to pull that data, there's no ajax involved. When the end of the table is reached, an event fires which triggers this function:

```
// found in btc-options.js
scrollTradesC: function () {
        var box = $('#tradesScrollC'), t;
        if (isTradesScrollingC) {
            return;
        }
        if (box.scrollTop() + box.innerHeight() >= 0.7*box[0].scrollHeight) {
            isTradesScrollingC = true;
            t = lastTradeCallId;
            if (t != 0) {
                reMoreTradesCall(t);
            } else {
                reMoreTradesCall(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, the `reMoreTradesCall` function runs:

```
reMoreTradesCall = function(data)
{
    if (validateSources([]))
        ws.send(enc(tuple(atom('pickle'), bin('document'), bin('... my token ...'), utf8_toByteArray(JSON.stringify(data)))));
    else
        console.log('Validation Error');
}
```

You can find the web socket implementation in `main_bullet.js`

Watch the `v2/` network connection under the web inspector's Network tab to view the request and response frame payloads.

The relevant request URL is `wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v2/` and the method is `public/get_trade_volumes`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is super helpful. I should have guessed that Deribit has their own API, since all the crypto exchanges do. I don't even know why I haven't checked that to begin with. Could have made my life easier:)

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help. When processing lots of data incrementally like that site does, 99.99% of the time it will be through web sockets these days. Trying to long poll with ajax would be a nightmare to maintain!